# Why 'import mmap' throws ImportError in jython

Tags: java, python, jython

I'm new to python and jython. I had a script in python which imports **mmap**, it works fine without any issues. I need to invoke a function in that script from a java class, which throws the following exception upon execution.

```
Exception in thread "main" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mmap
```

I executed the same script in jython which gives me the below error.

```
C:\jython2.5.3>jython.bat d:\Python\AddConfToFile.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\AddConfToFile.py", line 9, in <module>
    import mmap
ImportError: No module named mmap
```

I'm not able to find any suggestions through Google. Am I missing some thing here, kindly Help me fix this.

Thanks in Advance

Adithyan

Answer (score 0):

The `mmap` module is not available under Jython. You will need to find an alternative.

Comment: Is there any known alternative for this.. Actually my script imports pefile which includes mmap..

Answer (score 0):

It's just because the Jython doesn't  support mmap still..As explained in the [FAQ in the official site](http://www.jython.org/faq3.html), in the paragraph below:

> Modules that we don't support, and perhaps won't, include bsddb3, curses, dbm, gdbm, 
>   ioctl, ***mmap***, pty, Tkinter, and win32reg. Some of these might be readily doable, like 
>   mapping the curses module against CHARVA, but given limited resources, are not likely to 
>   be worked on. (Contributions welcome!)

Comment: Thanks for the information.. I should be looking for a way around to achieve my task..